# swift loop delay not working properly

Tags: swift, loops, delayed-execution

I am trying to animate an UIImageView to move across the screen.  In order to make the motion smooth, I need to use about 60 increments.  The code works well for increments 0-10 with each new increment happening after one second pause. However, for increments 10-20 it pauses 2 seconds and then executes the loop twice.  For 21-30 it pauses 3 seconds and executes the loop three times, so on.  Below is my loop:

```
    for i in 0...30 {
        let when = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(i)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
            let date = Date()
            let calendar = Calendar.current
            let second = calendar.component(.second, from: date)
            print("delay count = \(i), time = \(second))")
            self.ballView.frame = CGRect(x: ballPositionX, y: self.view.frame.size.height * 0.45, width: self.view.frame.size.width * 0.2, height: self.view.frame.size.height * 0.2)
            ballPositionX = ballPositionX + ballMoveX
        }
    }
```

You can see in the console log below the additive delay in loop execution by comparing the index (delay count) with the seconds (time) when the loop happens.

```
   delay count = 0, time = 10)
   delay count = 1, time = 11)
   delay count = 2, time = 12)
   delay count = 3, time = 13)
   delay count = 4, time = 14)
   delay count = 5, time = 16)
   delay count = 6, time = 17)
   delay count = 7, time = 18)
   delay count = 8, time = 19)
   delay count = 9, time = 19)
   delay count = 10, time = 21)
   delay count = 11, time = 22)
   delay count = 12, time = 22)
   delay count = 13, time = 25)
   delay count = 14, time = 25)
   delay count = 15, time = 27)
   delay count = 16, time = 27)
   delay count = 17, time = 29)
   delay count = 18, time = 29)
   delay count = 19, time = 31)
   delay count = 20, time = 31)
   delay count = 21, time = 33)
   delay count = 22, time = 33)
   delay count = 23, time = 33)
   delay count = 24, time = 37)
   delay count = 25, time = 37)
   delay count = 26, time = 37)
   delay count = 27, time = 40)
   delay count = 28, time = 40)
   delay count = 29, time = 40)
   delay count = 30, time = 43)
```

I have looked at other implementations for a delay in a loop, but generally their loops never go past 10 cycles.

Comment: why don't you just UIView.Animate with a time duration on a constraint constant, then call view.layoutIfNeeded() rather than what you're doing currently?

Comment: Agree with Jay, you could also look up 3rd party animation libraries that make it even easier.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve an animation is by setting parameter to view that you want to animate then call `UIView.animate` with one of its overloads and call for update the specific part

In your case you are updating the layout so you should call `layoutIfNeeded`

here is an example:

```
//calculating final frame (origin and size)
let x = ballPossitionX * 30
let y = self.view.frame.size.height * 0.45
let width = self.view.frame.size.width * 0.2
let height = self.view.frame.size.height * 0.2

ballView.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height

let animationTime = 2.0

UIView.animate(withDuration: animationTime) {
   self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

There are also some animated properties like `alpha` which can be added directly in animate block

Comment: The UIView.animate worked great.  I am still new to Xcode so I did not know about this feature.  As for the loop delay not working properly past 10 passes, I guess it is a bug.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Delph2 I'm not sure if this solved your problem or you still have some

Comment: You solved my problem in that my app is working the way I want it.  The delay in the loop not working properly is now just a curiosity, but not important for me to understand.  Thanks very much for your help.